# getNextDataRange() do google SpreadsheatApp com bug?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Olá me deparei com a seguinte situação: preciso apenas usar um método da classe `Selection` do Google SpreadsheetApp em um uma seleção ativada, mas ela está trazendo o seguinte bug:

```
ReferenceError: "Direction" não está definido.
```

Porém já olhei na [documentação a respeito do assunto](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getNextDataRange(Direction))
e segue que eu não consegui ainda encontrar o erro.

Porque Direction não está sendo reconhecido?

```
function ok() {
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PUT YOUR SPREADSHEET ID").getSheets()

  var s2 = s1[0]

  var s3 = s2.getRange("C4").activate()

  var s5 = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getNextDataRange(Direction.DOWN).getValues()

  var s4 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PUT YOUR SPREADSHEET ID").getRange("C5:C8").setValues(s5)

  return s4

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que `Direction` não é global e está dentro do objeto `SpreadsheetApp`. Segue a linha corrigida:

```
var s5 = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getValues()
```

Comment: Oi. Já aproveitando a discussão:


```function ok() {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").setActiveRange("B2").activateAsCurrentCell();
  SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.FORWARD)
}
```
                      
pela segunda vez  quando eu vou usar o Objeto SpreadsheetApp, a minha seleção anterior vai estar disponível?